# Functionality of a roof vent pipe

Tags: plumbing, roof

There is a pipe vent sticking out of the roof, in which I need to determine the functionality of.

[image]

What is this pipe vent for?

Comment: What plumbing fixtures are below it? It should be the vent for those fixtures.

Comment: There is a begin sink below it. Why does the plumbing for a sink need ventilation?

Comment: The waste (drain) pipes for all fixtures need a vent otherwise drainage is very slow. Also sewer gases need a place to vent that is not inside the home.

Comment: The vent (required by code) is to prevent a siphon effect from emptying the p-trap in your sink below and to vent the sewer gas outside the house

Comment: An excellent read for "Why does plumbing need ventilation?" even if your particular area uses a slightly different code: https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IPC2018/chapter-9-vents#IPC2018_Ch09_Sec911

Answer (score 4):

The vent (required by code) is to prevent a siphon effect from emptying the p-trap in your sink below and to vent the sewer gas outside the house.